# Confirm or validate underlining distribution association with survival analysis

Tags: r, distributions, survival, epidemiology, weibull-distribution

The following two question outline how one can plot the results from a survival analysis using R. [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151591/how-to-plot-the-survival-curve-generated-by-survreg-package-survival-of-r) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236939/plot-survival-and-hazard-function-of-survreg-using-curve)

But both of the examples assume, or more directly specify a weibull distribution fitted to the survival model.

Refering to `survreg()` which is within the `survival` package in R, the following are possible fitting assumptions:

- weibull
- exponential
- gaussian
- logistic
- lognormal
- loglogistic

So if we take the example from the `survreg()` help.

```
library(survival)

data(ovarian)

head(ovarian)

survival.weibull <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + strata(sex), 
                          dist='weibull', lung)

survival.logn <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + strata(sex), 
                            dist='lognormal', lung)

survival.logl <- survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + age + strata(sex), 
                         dist='loglogistic', lung)
```

How can one verify the best appropriate distribution to fit. From the summary statistic we get the `Loglik(model)` value. Is this the best indicator? Or is there a graphical method to visualise the best fit - I was suggested a QQ-plot may be of help.

Thanks in advance for an advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of log-likelihoods are problematic because not all the survival models are nested within one another. But you can use something like AIC or BIC, which can be obtained using `extractAIC()`. For example:

```
> extractAIC(survival.weibull)
[1]    5.000 2284.504
> extractAIC(survival.logn)
[1]    5.000 2315.142
> extractAIC(survival.logl) 
[1]    5.000 2297.171
```

This would suggest, based on AIC, that the Weibull model fits best. In terms of visualizing the best fit, you could plot all three parametric fits atop a non-parameteric Kaplan-Meier curve to visualize the fit of the parametric forms to the underlying data. The means to do that is in your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151591/how-to-plot-the-survival-curve-generated-by-survreg-package-survival-of-r).